# CSS Current Menu Item - ul li Class

Tags: css

Very basic CSS issue as I can't get the current page to look different in menu. Any suggestion greatly appreciated!

Here is the genesis function

```
//* Add My New Menu
function my_new_menu() {

echo '<ul class="menu gn responsive-menu">
<li class="menu-item"><a href="/kids-joke-book/"> New Joke Book!</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="/kids/"> Kids Jokes </a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="/animal-jokes/"> Animal Jokes /a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="/zoo-jokes/"> Zoo Jokes </a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="/joke-contest/"> Contest </a></li>
</ul>';

}
add_action( 'genesis_header_right', 'my_new_menu' );
```

Here is the CSS

```
.gn a {
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 3px;
color: #438ed9;
display: block;
font-weight: 400;
height: auto;
line-height: 1;
margin-top: 0.2rem;
padding: 0.8rem 1rem;
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
}

.gn a:hover,
.gn .current-menu-item > a,
.gn .sub-menu .current-menu-item > a:hover {
color: #fff;
background-color: #009900;
}
```

Comment: Add `current-menu-item` to the list-item class of the current page.

Comment: I tried this an triple checked it and it wasn't working. I stripped a wordpress genesis menu down to lighten the code and I pull it from the functions file. Basically, the page doesn't understand it's the current page. You can see it here: http://www.kidzjokes.com/

Comment: Show the code that you are using that determines what the current page is.

Comment: I added the function and the respective css...

Comment: There is nothing in your code that does the necessary work to set up the current page. In your PHP function, you need to look at the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or other server variable to compare against the URLs in your menu and add the `current-menu-item` class to the appropriate `li` element.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to add your ".current" class to the corresponding "li" item.
So, for example if you are on the "kids-joke-book" page your "ul" should look like this:

```
<ul class="menu gn responsive-menu">
<li class="menu-item current"><a href="/kids-joke-book/"> New Joke Book! </a></li>
......
</ul>
```

You should do this method on every single subpage of your site where you use this menu, and add the "current" class to the correct menu item.
("current" class is an example name, it has the styles what you would like to add to the right menu item.)

Comment: "active" is also a great class since its context can be used for several occasions such as buttons, selects, form fields and menus.

Comment: What if i add an id to the menu item? I don't have on-page functionality as stripped a wordpress genesis menu down to lighten the code and I pull it from the functions file. Basically, the page doesn't understand it's the current page. You can see it here: kidzjokes.com

Comment: Adding an id in this case is really the same solution. As i think when you click on a link a new page opens. Then in the HTML code of all page you should add the id / class to the corresponding "li" item. So in page1.html:
<li class="menu-item current"><a href="/kids-joke-book/"> New Joke Book! </a></li> 
But in page2.html:
<li class="menu-item"><a href="/kids-joke-book/"> New Joke Book! </a></li>

<li class="menu-item current"><a href="/kids/"> Kids Jokes </a></li> --> the second page is the current here. I hope it is understandable.

Comment: HI NeuDav, thanks for you advice so far... The problem is the pages are generated via the wp genesis functions and I don't have control of the menu via individual pages. Using the standard Genesis menu is heavier code than what is needed with all the extra classes. Ideally, I'll lighten the classes when it's working...